# Is there a way to automatically delete an aws codepipeline after a certain time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I am pretty new to the AWS services so please bear with me here. I am currently working on a project where I am trying to shut down the live environments (on aws codepipeline) after 24 hours. It seems like there isn’t an option to set a time limit on a pipeline during creation. Given that, is there a good way to do something like this? I was thinking of creating some sort of lambda function that can be triggered externally to delete a certain pipeline (since it seems like it is [possible to run aws cli codes with lambda](https://alestic.com/2016/11/aws-lambda-awscli/)). But again, I am still very new to this and am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Are you executing your shutdown code from Code Pipeline or are the environments hosted by Code Pipeline?

Comment: The environment is hosted by the pipeline. I was thinking of executing the shutdown code either directly from lambda or via some external trigger that executes shutdown lambda.

Comment: Are you using the deploy step in CodePipeline? If so, what method are you using?

Comment: No. After a build, it is application step (unless you mean this by the deploy step) on a EBStack.

Comment: why do you want to delete `Code Pipeline`? They don't incur any charges. Also, deleting a `Code Pipeline` does not delete the resources it created. You will have to delete the `CFT Stack` that actually created the resources.

Comment: AWS CodePipeline costs $1 per active pipeline per month. There are also additional charges depending on your pipeline artifacts in Amazon S3 and for triggering actions from other AWS and third-party services that you connect to your pipeline. In any case, I am looking to delete them and if deleting the stack is necessary, I may want to do it at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured a way out myself. The easiest way seems to be creating a Cloudwatch rule that is scheduled for every hour or day that invokes a lambda function. Below is the boto3 lambda function I created to sort through the Codestar for pipelines that are older than 24 hours and deleting them.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

# 24 hours limit from lambda invocation
timeLimit = (datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=24))

# Create an Codestar client
client = boto3.client('codestar', region_name='us-east-1')

# begins lambda function
def lambda_handler(event, context):

# Call Codestar to list current projects
response = client.list_projects()

# Get a list of all project ids from the response
projectIds = [projects['projectId'] for projects in response['projects']]

# Iterate through projects
for projectId in projectIds:

        # Gets time stamp for each project
        description = client.describe_project(id=projectId)

        # If a project is older than 24 hours, then the project is deleted
        if description['createdTimeStamp'] < timeLimit:
            response = client.delete_project(id=projectId, deleteStack=True)
```

Comment: How did you deal with cleaning up other parts of the pipeline such as IAM roles, deployment bucket etc related to a pipeline you want to delete?